# How to remove action bar in react native

Tags: react-native

Hi I am developing an android app with react native. i am trying to remove the action bar(Home) from HomeScreen.js my code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>HomeScreen</Text>
          </View>
        );
   }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
     },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQJ2p.png)

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: yes i am using react navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using React Navigation, The Stack Navigator has a header by default, you need to give the value of null to the header prop for navigationOptions.

You can add this function in your HomeScreen class.

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    };
```

Comment: So i need to add the above code in each every component or is there any default way to disable the action bar

Comment: Got it thanks, i added the defaultNavigationOption(){ header : null}  function directly to the createStackNavigator()

Answer (score 3):

For a single screen, you can set the property `headerShown:false` in Stack.Screen as:

```
<Stack.Screen
  name="AppScreen1"
  component={AppScreen1}
  options={{headerShown: false}}
/>
```

For all screens at once, set the property `headerShown:false` using screenOptions in Stack.Navigator as:

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
>
  <Stack.Screen>
    ---
  </Stack.Screen>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: options={{headerShown: false}} this line did the trick for me, thanks.